# Trying to understand ES6 modules. The event listeners inside modules doesn't get triggered

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

I have three modules

- form-validator.js
- upload.js
- product.js

The **form-validator.js** module is imported inside **upload.js** module. And both **upload.js** and **product.js** are added as script tags of type module inside sidepanel.html file . The html file contains a form with an select element.

**sidepanel.html**

```
<head>
    <script type="module" src="~/js/upload.js" defer></script>
  <script type="module" src="~/js/product.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="upload-form">
        <div class="form-group form-element validate-custom">
            <label class="form-label required_element" for="product-list">Product:</label>
            <select id="productNameList" class="form-select" name="productNameList" data-role="multiselect"></select>
            <div class="custom-validation-error"></div>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

Inside the **upload.js** file, I have this section of code.

```
import * as formValidatorModule from "./modules/form_validator.js";

const uploadForm = document.getElementById("upload-form");
const productNameElem = document.getElementById("productNameList");
const formValidator = new formValidatorModule.FormValidator(uploadForm);
formValidator.register(productNameElem , someValidationFunc);
```

and inside the form_validator.js module I have the FormValidator class with **register** function that takes in the form element (i.e) productNameElem in this case and the validation function and adds an **change event listener** to that formElement.

```
export class FormValidator {

    constructor(form) {
        this.form = form;
        this.inputElementsWithErrors = new Set();
    }

    register(inputElem, validationFunc) {

        const errorElem = inputElem.closest(".validate-custom").querySelector(".custom-validation-error");
        const executeErrorValidationFunc = () => {
            const { isValid, errorMessage } = validationFunc(inputElem);
            errorElem.innerHTML = errorMessage || "";

            if (!isValid)
                this.inputElementsWithErrors.add(inputElem);
            else
                this.inputElementsWithErrors.delete(inputElem);

        }

        inputElem.addEventListener("change", executeErrorValidationFunc);
    }
}
```

And now if I trigger the change event of that formElement inside the **product.js** file it doesn't trigger the change event, the event handler does not execute.

```
const productNameElem = document.getElementById("productNameList");
productNameElem.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"))
```

So I am trying to understand why it doesn't work, does it have something to do with the scope of the modules.

I recently learned modules and trying to solidify my knowlege by doing some practice. So could someone please clarify why it doesn't work in this scenario.

Comment: Why are you passing a `formElem` to `register`? Why don't you use `this.form` that you passed to the constructor?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl the formElem is not the uploadForm. I am passing the productNameElem in the register function. It is the input element inside the form which we register for various validations. I have renamed the variable to inputElem. Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: I updated my response below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would help if you included the HTML. Here is my attempt at reverse-engineering your HTML.

I registered the `filename` input in my example below with:

```js
formValidator.register(uploadForm.elements.filename, filenameValidator);
```

You can access form elements (inputs) via: `<formElement>.elements.<name>`

### `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Custom Validation with Modules</title>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      form {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
        gap: 0.5rem;
      }
      form > button[type="submit"] {
        grid-column: 1/3;
      }
      .custom-validation-error {
        color: red;
        font-size: smaller;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="./upload.mjs" type="module"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Upload form</h1>
      <form action="POST" id="upload-form">
        <label for="filename-input">Filename</label>
        <div class="validate-custom">
          <input
          id="filename-input"
          name="filename"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter a filename..."
          required
        />
        <div class="custom-validation-error"></div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="productNameList"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### `upload.mjs`

```js
import FormValidator from "./modules/form_validator.mjs";

// Elements
const uploadForm = document.getElementById("upload-form");

const formValidator = new FormValidator(uploadForm);

/**
 * @typedef {object} ValidationResult
 * @property {boolean} isValid - wether the form is valid
 * @property {string} errorMessage - the error message
 */

/**
 *
 * @param {HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement} inputEl
 * @returns {ValidationResult} result
 */
const filenameValidator = (inputEl) => {
  let isValid = true;
  let errorMessage = "";

  if (inputEl.value.trim().length === 0) {
    isValid = false;
    errorMessage = "Filename is required";
  }

  return { isValid, errorMessage };
};

formValidator.register(uploadForm.elements.filename, filenameValidator);
```

### `modules/form_validator.mjs`

```js
export default class FormValidator {
  constructor(form) {
    this.form = form;
    this.inputElementsWithErrors = new Set();
  }

  register(inputEl, validationFunc) {
    const errorElem = inputEl
      .closest(".validate-custom")
      .querySelector(".custom-validation-error");

    const executeErrorValidationFunc = (e) => {
      const { isValid, errorMessage } = validationFunc(inputEl);
      errorElem.innerHTML = errorMessage || "";

      if (!isValid) this.inputElementsWithErrors.add(inputEl);
      else this.inputElementsWithErrors.delete(inputEl);
    };

    inputEl.addEventListener("change", executeErrorValidationFunc);
  }
}
```